# javascript use return of one function inside another

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, hoisting

I have a function A, that uses a function B inside, i want to use the return variable from function B inside function A but it always gives me undefined.

I've searched a lot on the web for answers but im getting hopeless.

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    
    
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973);
    
    ....

    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    **latlng=codeAddress("lisboa")**;
    
    
  }



function codeAddress(a) {

    
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': a}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     
      latlong=results[0].geometry.location;
      
        alert(latlong);
        return latlong;
        
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need a callback.

Comment: @SLaks I think you're right but like, _how do it know_?

Comment: when i use the function "codeAddress" the variable is lost in between. it gets a correct alert executing the function, but then it fails to atribute the value to "latlng"

Comment: if `latlng=codeAddress("lisboa")` results in `undefined` you should show how the function `codeAddress` looks like.

Comment: ive added function B to the question

Comment: ive made latlong a window variable, since i read somewhere it could be the solution...still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a call back to handle the results:

```
function initialize() {
    .... // your code
codeAddress(function(res){
    alert(res);
});         


function codeAddress(callback) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973);
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(res, sta) {
      if (sta== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
      {
        if (res[1]) 
            callback(res[1].formatted_address);
        else 
            alert("Nothing found");
      }

  });
}
}
```